# gnuplot and c++ and pipes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, charts, plot, gnuplot

I am pretty new to all of this. Here is my problem.

I have the opening of a pipe to gnuolot from VS2010 c++ as per "FILE *p = _popen", this seems to work as I a graph appears eventually.

I have an infinite loop which is broken by a 'flick of a switch'  directly following the pipe opening and the sending of the commands to 'gnuplot' within the int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {} structure

It seems as if this loop is somehow blocking the production of the graph in gnuplot as it only appears when I intentionally break the infinite loop or possibly 'hogging' all the processor time.

My main,eventual aim here is to open a pipe to gnuplot and then plot a variable from my c++ program  real-time in gnuplot.

Comment: Output to pipes is buffered by default. You should call `fflush` when you want to force the data to be sent to the pipe.

Comment: BarMar - maybe a fflush command might force the commands to be sent to  the pipe before the loop...will try this ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, I thought you were sending commands to gnuplot within the loop. If you're done sending to gnuplot, you should call `pclose`.

Comment: Hey BarMar ..that worked ...seems like the commands were 'lurking' around ...breaking the loop with break; exit(0)...possibly had the effect of flushing everything to gnuplot. Incidentally I have placed fflush commands after each fprintf command to make sure that they are executed at the right time

Comment: If you're going to do that, it would be easier to call `setbuf` to tell it not to buffer in the first place.

Comment: Do yo perhaps know how to hold the graph open in gnuplot without using pause commands...at the moment i am using "plot sin(x)-persist" which doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about gnuplot. You should post a new question about that.

Comment: Barmar - I would actually like to send data to gnuplot within the loop for plotting ....

Comment: Barmar - post an answer , I will click it ad post another gnuplot question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that stdio buffers output to pipes by default. Solutions are:

1. Call `fflush` when you want to force data to the pipe.
2. Call `fflush` after each output operation.
3. Call `setbuf` after opening the pipe, to disable buffering.
4. Call `pclose` when you're finished sending to the pipe, and all the buffered data will be flushed.

Comment: Nice ... i used setvbuf (p, NULL, _IONBF,NULL ); to disabl the buffering